# How to use a subquery result for another sql select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use the result of a `sql` query and send another query based on the result.

Exmaple (of course real live query is more complex):

```
table1: name, age
table2: name, age, field1, fieldN
```

First query:

```
select name, age from table1 where age > 18.
```

Now I'd like to find all entries from table2 that match the *multiple* resulting fields of the first query.

Important note: I want to retrieve the **full** rows of table2 where the match is.

But how?

Comment: @shravster I'd like to match on any fields of the first result query. In my example: name + age. So I'd like to find the rows where both the name+age matches in one row. And iterate for the full result of query1..

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Query build based on MS sql server

```
select t1.* 
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2 on t1.name=t2.name and t1.age=t2.age
where t2.age > 18
```

Comment: No, I'd like to select the full row of table2 where the resulting tuple of query1 matches.

Comment: did not get your point currently, but i think your answer is as below

    select t1.* 
    from table1 as t1
    join table2 as t2 on t1.name=t2.name and t1.age=t2.age
    where t2.age > 18

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically join based on matching column names, then you can use a `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
WITH query1 AS (
    SELECT age, name FROM table1 WHERE age > 18
)
SELECT age, name, t2.field1, t2.fieldN
FROM table2 t2 NATURAL JOIN query1;
```

Now, while `NATURAL JOIN` is generally not recommended, as it is really weak because your queries using it can easily brake due to schema changes, it may be OK for hand ad-hoc queries, or for queries, like the above, where you can make the columns used explicit. In either case, I advise against it and use the common join style:

```
WITH query1 AS (
    SELECT age, name FROM table1 WHERE age > 18
)
SELECT t2.age, t2.name, t2.field1, t2.fieldN
FROM table2 t2 JOIN query1 q1 ON t2.age = q1.age AND t2.name = t1.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I'd like to:

- find
- all entries from table2
- that match the multiple resulting fields
- of the first query

---

```
SELECT *         -- find
FROM table2 t2   -- from t2
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.name = t2.name -- that match
    AND t1.age = t2.age     -- Huh? "multiple matching fields" ?
    AND t1.age > 18         -- with the same condition
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is what I was looking for, but thanks for any help:

```
select * from table2 where (name, age) IN (
    select name, age from table1 where age > 18
)
```

Comment: I don't know, but if it is I'd perfer this solution over joins as it reads more clear.